# What is the proper way to use Socket.IO callbacks within classes in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using Node.JS with Socket.IO and Express. My goal is to create a module that creates a custom Socket.IO+Express server, loaded with all the functions that my application needs. For example, keeping track of the number of clients connected at any given time.

The catch is, I'd like to have the server work as a class, if possible. I've seen other Node.JS modules use classes just fine (including Socket.IO itself) so I assume it shouldn't conflict with Node's module-oriented architecture. The reason why I need it to work with classes is that I want to be able to create multiple instances of the server with ease.

Here's what I have (simplified for brevity):

**index.js**

```
var myserver = require("./myserver");
var myserver1 = myserver.createServer();
var myserver2 = myserver.createServer();

myserver1.port = 8080;
myserver2.port = 8081;

myserver1.start();
myserver2.start();
```

**myserver.js**

```
var io = require("socket.io");
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");

function MyServer()
{
     this.port = 8080;
     this.expressServer = null;
     this.ioServer = null;

     this.clientCount = 0;
}

Server.prototype.getClientCount = function()
{
    return this.clientCount;
}

Server.prototype.start = function()
{
    this.expressServer = express.createServer();
    this.ioServer      = io.listen(this.expressServer);
    this.expressServer.listen(this.port);

    this.ioServer.sockets.on(
        "connection",
        function()
        {
            this.clientCount++;
            console.log(this.clientCount + " clients connected.");
        }
    );
}

exports.createServer = function() { return new MyServer(); };
```

The code inside the `"connection"` callback is incorrect, because the `this` keyword in Socket.IO's callback refers to the *client* object that triggered the `"connection"` event, not to the `MyServer` object. So is there a way to access the `clientCount` property from inside the callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a proper closure by copying `this` into <s>another</s> a variable (most people like to call it `self` but some prefer `that`) and using it in your connection handler:

```
var self=this;
this.ioServer.sockets.on(
    "connection",
    function()
    {
        self.clientCount++;
        console.log(self.clientCount + " clients connected.");
    }
);
```

Comment: It works! I had previously tried to create a `self` variable for this purpose, but I had created it only in the constructor. I didn't realize it had to be created in the `start` method as well.